# Spi transfer on arduino equivalent on universal windows platform

Tags: c++, arduino, spi, windows-10-iot-core

How can i write this example on UWP windows 10 core iot c++?

```
unsigned char RFID::readMFRC522(unsigned char addr)
{
    unsigned char val;

    SPI.transfer(((addr << 1) & 0x7E) | 0x80);
    val = SPI.transfer(0x00);

    return val;
}
```

On windows exists "void Write(byte[])", "void Read(byte[])", "void TransferFullDuplex(byte[] write, byte[] read)", "void TransferSequential(byte[] write, byte[] read)".

On arduino exists "byte transfer(byte)", i think.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you might find your needs in using the Windows.Devices.Spi.SpiDevice class.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Dn708164(v=win.10).aspx